# how to create textbox with radio button dynamically in jquery

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery-ui

When I am clicking the button a new row is created with textbox and radio button. But while clicking on the radio button in one row, then the other radio buttons of other rows are deselected.

But I want to keep the radio button selected state even if I click other radio buttons.

This is my code:

```
<html>
<head>   
    <title>Add More Elements</title>
    <script src="../practice/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready (function () {
            $('.btnAdd').click (function () {       
                $('.buttons').append('<div><input type="text" name="txt">M<input type="radio" id="m" name="gender">F<input type="radio" id="f" name="gender"><input type="checkbox" name="txt"><br></div>'); // end append

            }); // end click                

        }); // end ready
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>This Is Create Textboxs Dinamically </p>
    <div class="buttons">
         <table><tr><td>Name:</td><td>Gender:</td><td>Choice:</td><td><input type="button" class="btnAdd" value="Click Me To Create TextBox"><br></td></tr>
       <tr> <td><input type="text" name="txt"></td><td>M<input type="radio" id="m" name="gender">F<input type="radio" id="f" name="gender"></td><td><input type="checkbox" name="txt"></td><td></td> </tr>
        </table>     
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

if the radio button cannot be deselected upon clicking the same one, you might aswell use checkboxes.

Comment: only one radio option is selected ,if second is one selected then first is deselected

Answer (score 0):

If radio buttons have same name, they will deselect each other. Try asigning different names to each group of radio buttons

```
M<input type="radio" id="m" name="gender[0]">
F<input type="radio" id="f" name="gender[0]">

M<input type="radio" id="m" name="gender[1]">
F<input type="radio" id="f" name="gender[1]">
```

Answer (score 0):

Your radios are all of the same name.

You can group them in pairs by adding an index key

```
 <input type='radio' name='grouping[1]' />
 <input type='radio' name='grouping[1]' />
 <input type='radio' name='grouping[2]' />
 <input type='radio' name='grouping[2]' />
```

Answer (score 0):

you gave same name to radio buttons , although their ids are unique but they have same name , so either use different names or use check boxes

Answer (score 0):

You are appending the radio buttons and the input text with the same name and ids `id="m"`. In a page controls can not have same ids. Try to assign them different-2 ids.

```
var count=0;
 $(document).ready (function () {
            $('.btnAdd').click (function () {  
count++;     
                $('.buttons').append('<div><input type="text" name="txt">M<input type="radio" id="m"+count+" name="gender">F<input type="radio" id="f" name="gender"><input type="checkbox" name="txt"><br></div>'); // end append

            }); // end click                

        }); // end ready
```

Use count in ids.

Answer (score 0):

Becuse all your radio buttons have the same name property they are all of the same group. you have to make each group unique by giving it a unique id e.g identify the row itself by a running number...

HTML:

```
</head>
<body>
    <p>This Is Create Textboxs Dinamically </p>
    <div class="buttons">
         <table><tr><td>Name:</td><td>Gender:</td><td>Choice:</td><td><input type="button" class="btnAdd" value="Click Me To Create TextBox"><br></td></tr>
       <tr> <td><input type="text" name="txt"></td><td>M<input type="radio" id="m" name="gender">F<input type="radio" id="f" name="gender"></td><td><input type="checkbox" name="txt"></td><td></td> </tr>
        </table>


    </div>
</body>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var rowCount = 0;
    $('.btnAdd').click(function () {
        $('.buttons').append('<div id="row"' + rowCount + '><input type="text" name="txt">M<input type="radio" id="m" name="genderForRow"' + rowCount + '>F<input type="radio" id="f" name="genderForRow"' + rowCount + '><input type="checkbox" name="txt"><br></div>'); // end append
        rowCount++;
    }); // end click                

}); // end ready
```

see fiddle [link here...](http://jsfiddle.net/)